# How to apply CSS to first child div element only?

Tags: html, css

```
<div class = "node-master">
  <div class = "node-1">
    <div class ="node-content">
      child content 1
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class = "node-2">
    <div class ="node-content">
      child content 2
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

In example above, I need to target "child content 1" CSS class to apply a different font color. However, the caveat is I cannot target `node-1` directly because of how the HTML is being generated (dynalist.io app).

The setting dictating "child content 1" CSS syntax is from `node-master`.

Basically, what I need to do is have a CSS class that uses node-master and applies its properties to the first child `<div>`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can play with `:first-child` CSS selector, for example if you want to target the first `div` child of `.node-master`:

```
.node-master > div:first-child {
 color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `:first-child` pseudo selector on the parent:

```css
.node-master div:first-child div.node-content {
  color: red;
}
.node-content {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="node-master">
  <div class="node-1">
    <div class="node-content">
      child content 1
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="node-2">
    <div class="node-content">
      child content 2
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the css to target elements without classes

```
 .node-master > div:nth-child(1){background-color:red;}
 .node-master > div:nth-child(2){background-color:blue;}
 ...
 .node-master > div:nth-child(n){background-color:red;}
```

Hope this may help
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have each of the node-contents be unique for the css to appear

```
<div class = "node-master">
  <div class = "node-1">
    <div class ="node-content1">
      child content 1
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class = "node-2">
    <div class ="node-content2">
      child content 2
    </div>
</div>
```

And then simply set the color property.

```
.node-content1 {
  color: #1e00ef
}

.node-content2 {
  color: #f44336
}
```

Here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/fvw3xhv8/